# how to change y axis, x axis in bar chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am a new employee of this company and previous guy used d3.js tool to draw bar chart. Now we have the problem that x-axis have too many labels and label text are mixed, so it is hard to see the chart.

I want to swap x-axis and y-axis

This is running with Java Spring

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseLength ; i++) {
 rmaCmplCodeName = parsedResponse[i].rmaCmplCodeName;
 number = parsedResponse[i].number;   
 discreteBarChart[0] 
["values"].push({"label":number,"value":rmaCmplCodeName});  
                      };
discreteBarChartFunc(discreteBarChart); 


function discreteBarChartFunc(discreteBarChart) {
nv.addGraph(function() { 
    var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()                            
        .x(function(d) {                                
            return d.label })
        .y(function(d) {
                        d3.format('d');      
            return d.value })
                    .staggerLabels(true)                 
                    .valueFormat(d3.format('d'))
                    .showValues(true)
                    .duration(250)

           chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('d'));  

       d3.select('#chart svg')

               .datum(discreteBarChart)

               .transition().duration(500)                      
       .call(chart);


            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);                            
    return chart;
    });
}
```

Comment: Without a minimum set of data, it is hard for people to reproduce or visualise what's going on.

Comment: nvd3 is a package build on top of d3 library, to provide a level of abstraction, however, it has a smaller user community and a new set of APIs to learn, if you could provide a dataset (i.e. your discreteBarChart object) structure, and show how your existing chart look like, and what you wish to achieve, maybe it will be better to replace the nvd3 with generic d3 chart.